# angular 2 dynamic checkboxes with iteration

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

[image]

Hi,

I'm having a hard time to find a solution to my requirement. I want to generate checkboxes dynamically like the above image.

Data from the API will come in below format.

```js
  vaultsNamesValues: any = {
    SMDD: ['SMDD1', 'SMDD2', 'SMDD3', 'SMDDZ1', 'SMDDZ2', 'SMDDZ2'],
    DCRT: ['DCRTZ1', 'DCRTZ2', 'DCRTZ3', 'DCRTZ4'],
    MISS: ['MISS1', 'MISS2']
  }
```

I was able to generate them but want to set the indeterminate state for the main checkbox whenever one or more sub checkboxes selected like https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/checkbox#select-all

I have created stackblitz with current code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htl6b2?file=app%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.ts

Can anyone please help me?